# Create table of differences

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I have a sheet of data to which I have run several macros to identify differences, I am now looking to create a matrix table which shows me the differences per column per department.

This is how my sheet looks after it has identified differences:

[DifferencesSheet] http://imgur.com/na6nvNH

And this is what I want to get to:

[FinalSheet] https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fh56.jpg

I currently have image 1 which is a table of highlighted differences and I need to create  matrix department on the y-axis vs. column headers along the x-axis and the amount of differences per column

Not sure if I can use a pivot table as the data is always changing.

Any advice will help thanks.

Comment: How about using chart?

Answer (score 0):

Chart will be more suitable as you got 2 manupulations

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to get from the first image to the second image. i.e i have a table of highlighted differences and i am trying to create the grid of the amount of differences per column per department

Answer (score 0):

### Use MS Query:

```
SELECT outTab.Department, SUM(outTab.DepartmentCode), SUM(outTab.Sales)
FROM 
(SELECT 
    S1.Department, 
    Iif(S1.DepartmentCode=S2.DepartmentCode,0,1) as DepartmentCode,
    Iif(S1.Sales=S2.Sales,0,1) as Sales 
FROM [Sales$] as S1 
INNER JOIN [Compare$] as S2 ON S1.ID = S2.ID) AS outTab
GROUP BY outTab.Department
```

You need to add the remaining columns above - I added the first two `DepartmentCode` and `Sales`. To refresh you will need to only right-click and hit `Refresh`.

### How to create an MS Query in Excel?

Two ways:

1. Go to <kbd>Data</kbd>-><kbd>From Other Sources</kbd>-><kbd>From Microsoft Query</kbd>
2. Download my SQL AddIn (free and open sources) [here][4] and just input the output range of the query (F1) and input the SQL and hit <kbd>Ok</kbd>

Comment: what will this produce, a matrix of differences as the second image?

Comment: when I follow your instructions as above, I choose excel as the datasource and it comes up with an error that no tables were found

Comment: That's why I use the SQL AddIn. However using the `Data`->`From Other Sources`->`From Microsoft Query`. Create a new data source, select an `Microsoft Excel Driver` and select your current workbook. Then prepare and edit the MS Query.

Comment: Unfortunately keep running into errors with this method! I appreciate the help..will continue to try and adapt and use it!

Comment: Start from a simple query (maybe just `SELECT * FROM [YourWorksheet$]`) then start building it up (edit the query by right-clicking on it and pasting the new one). Make sure the names of the worksheets are right (in above example I used my own Worksheets).